# How to show the value of all linked axes in tool tip in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I have linked two x axis to my master x axis and I want to be able to show all three axis in the tool tip. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter).

Comment: Its only used to format the values in the tool tip. how to get the shared axis in it?

Comment: In Highcharts we don't have shared axis, only linked. And formatter is to format tooltip, not values in tooltip. For example you have access to xAxis array this way: `this.series.chart.xAxis`.

Comment: how to access the linked axis array?

Comment: All axes are on the same level. To determine if axis is linked check: `xAxis[index].isLinked`. And if axis is linked to parent, then you have access to parent axis: `xAxis[index].linkedParent`.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Could you first create some sample which I can work with? jsFiddle should be enough.

Comment: I want to be able to show the second x axis ( one, two, three, four) in the tooltip. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h295m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example how to get categories of all axes: http://jsfiddle.net/h295m/1/

Code:

```
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var p = this.point,
                    s = p.series,
                    c = s.chart,
                    axes = c.xAxis,
                    aLen = axes.length,
                    i = 0,
                    str = '';

                for(i; i < aLen; i++){
                    str += axes[i].categories[p.x] + '<br>'; 
                }

                str += s.name + ': ' + p.y; 

                return str;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, But I am not able to use 'this' keyword inside the formatter function.this.point is undefined Any idea why?

Comment: If you have shared tooltip, then instead of `this.point` use something like `this.points[0]`.

Comment: categories is an array , what does categories[p.x] reference to?

Comment: `p.x`  is point.x value, when using categories, it's the same as category index. So `categories[p.x]` is category for specific point.